# Formula for a workflow rule

Tags: formula, workflow

I'd like to have a workflow rule fire when a record is owned by queue A and then changes owner.

What I have so far is:

```
AND(
ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) = 'QueueId'
)
```

I've tried both the QueueId and just the Id of the QueueSObject for the PRIORVALUE check.  The rule does not fire. Is it not possible to look up the OwnerId prior value at that time when the rule is evaluated?

Comment: This is solved.  As it turns out, I was using the wrong Id to use for the comparison operator.  I actually thought I has to use the 15 character Id, but it turns out that the 12 character version is good enough.

Comment: akarnid, please post the solution as an answer.

Comment: I'll be sure to do that when I can remember which validation rule this was.   Big org, lots of rules, and this being 3 months old does not help me remembering :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to use ISCHANGED() and PRIORVALUE(), you must setup your workflow rule to fire "Every time a record is created or edited."

Comment: Correct, but that wasn't the problem, see my comment above :)

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it... it was worth a try, since a common problem with ISCHANGED() is when the WF evaluates.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the scenario and works for me. 
Have you tried setting up the debug log and check if the workflow is firing or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help also? http://salesforceblogger.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/escalation-queues-and-workflows.html

Use the BEGINS(OwnerId, "00G") as part of the criteria formula.

It worked for me.